# How to save changes of lua-file with NLua

Tags: c#, lua

I have a very large lua file, that contains data I want to manipulate. Then I want to save it back to a new lua file. I am using NLua to read out the structure and change information. However, I did not find any way to **save those changes** anyhow.
This is my code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Lua lua = new Lua();
    lua.DoFile("C:\\temp\\mission.lua");

    LuaTable mission = lua.GetTable("mission");
    var coalitions = Search(mission, "coalition");
    var blue = Search(coalitions.First(), "blue");
    var planes = Search(blue.First(), "plane");
    var groups = Search(planes.First(), "group");

    foreach (var group in groups)
    {
        foreach (long groupId in group.Keys)
        {
            bool groupSet = false;
            var groupX = (LuaTable)group[groupId];
            var units = Search(groupX, "units");
            
            foreach (long unitId in units.First().Keys)
            {
                var unitX = (LuaTable)units.First()[unitId];

                if(!groupSet)
                {
                    groupX["name"] = unitX["type"] + $"-{++counter}";
                    groupSet = true;
                }

                unitX["name"] = groupX["name"] + $"-{unitId}";                    
            }
        }
    }

    // Not implemented yet
    WriteFile("C:\\temp\\WWII_Mixed_Combat\\mission2.lua", mission);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

"Search" is a function to look for LuaTable-Objects with the given name.